# swiftmailer - html and email templates

Tags: emails

I need to create a HTML email, and someone suggested [Swiftmailer](https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer). I installed that module, but it's not clear to me how to create HTML.

I enabled SwiftMailer as the sitewide default in the [Mail System](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem) module, and I added a message like this:

```
$string = "This is a defined message: You have been send a message - \n" .$params['message'] . '\n <a href="http://wwww.google.com">click here</a><button type="button">Click me</button>';
```

But the HTML isn't picked up. The `a` tag is a link, but the button is not a button. I also can't apply inline styles.

Additionally, I will need to know how to create **multiple email templates**, which apply to different email types (I only saw online how to create one, `swiftmailer.tpl.php`)

Answer (score 3):

Swiftmailer just sends emails ... it doesn't let you create HTML / plaintext content for emails.

For ease of setting this all up you likely want to use a module that supports the [Mime Mail](https://drupal.org/project/mimemail) module and then at least use something like [Previewable Email Templates (PET)](https://drupal.org/project/pet) module. Quote from the PET module page:

> The Previewable Email Template (PET) module lets you create email templates, with token substitution, which can be previewed by the user before sending. The emails can be sent to one or many email addresses in a flexible way, and the recipients may or may not be Drupal account holders (users).
>
> PET stores templates in a db table, not the variables table, so there is none of the memory usage which goes with the latter.
>
> PET templates are in one place for easy management by site administrators. Emails can be sent one of three ways:
>
> - interactively, from a link.
> - programmatically, in response to any situation.
> - via a Rules action (D7 only).

Comment: I installed the Mim Mail module, and it was automatically set as the site wide default in the Mail Systems settings section. Now mail wasn't getting sent out (even though drupal did pop up with a message saying it was sent properly). When I set it back to Default Mail System, it worked. What is wrong?

Comment: I dont know you have to check your email logs, php logs, apache logs. "Why email isn't going out" is a Server issue (even if Drupal said it went OK). Did you check your drupal status report page and Mime Mail configuration settings ?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the log, and Mime Mail doesn't have too many settings in the first place. I don't see what else I could set. It can't be a permission thing because I am logged in as Admin

Comment: sorry i have no other advice to give at this time. PHP doesn't send the email, your mail server does. Did an email get written to your mail queue? Is your email setup ok? The answer I've given to the question is all i can help with at this time.

Comment: how can you see if mail has been written to your mail queue?

Comment: SwiftMailer provides simple templates with its [Decorator plugin](http://www.sitepoint.com/sending-email-with-swift-mailer/).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [MIME mail](https://drupal.org/project/mimemail) (it requires [mailsystem](https://drupal.org/project/mailsystem) module)

> This is a Mime Mail component module (for use by other modules).
>
> It permits users to receive HTML email and can be used by other
>   modules. The mail functionality accepts an HTML message body,
>   mime-endcodes it and sends it. If the HTML has embedded graphics,
>   these graphics are MIME-encoded and included as a message attachment.
>   Adopts your site's style by automatically including your theme's
>   stylesheet files in a themeable HTML message format If the recipient's
>   preference is available and they prefer plaintext, the HTML will be
>   converted to plain text and sent as-is. Otherwise, the email will be
>   sent in themeable HTML with a plaintext alternative. Allows you to
>   theme messages with a specific mailkey. Converts CSS styles into
>   inline style attributes. Provides simple system actions and Rules
>   actions to send HTML email with embedded images and attachments.